# How do I connect to mysql without having to type an empty password?

Tags: mysql, security, password, client

I just installed MySQL, and by default the root user has no password. If I connect with this command:

```
mysql --port=3307 --host=127.0.0.1 -uroot -p
```

It asks me to enter a password, I just hit return, and it connects me. However, I want to make this part of a script, by piping a statement to it non-interactively, like this:

```
echo "$statement" | mysql --port=3307 --host=127.0.0.1 -uroot -p
```

But, when I actually do that, it still asks me for the password. How do I make it NOT ask for the password, and just not use one?

I tried removing the -p, and I get this message:

```
$ mysql --port=3307 --host=127.0.0.1 -uroot
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I would expect there to be some sort of --nopassword argument, but I can't find one.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer is actually to use the -p -- the long version allows you to set it to empty, like so:

```
mysql --port=3307 --host=127.0.0.1 -uroot --password=
```

Answer (score 1):

If your MySQL client/server version is a 5.6.x a way to avoid the `WARNING` message or putting a `password in command line`, you can use the [**mysql_config_editor**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html) tools:

```
    mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=username --password
```

Then you can use in your shell script:

```
    mysql --login-path=local  -e "statement"
```

Instead of:

```
    mysql -u $Username -p$Pass -e "statement"
```